# Is it possible to run js file on flash drive automatically when it's plugged in?

Tags: javascript, automation, window.open

I am trying to make a flash drive that automatically runs a simple `window.open()` when plugged in. Is this possible?

Note: The operating system I am using is ChromeOS. If it's not possible to do on ChromeOS, can you do it on Windows?

Comment: I would advise not using an operating system that made such a thing possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

The ability to run files automatically from a flash drive was [removed in Windows 7](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/autorun-inf-does-not-work-in-windows-7-anymore/), for [security reasons](https://www.cisa.gov/uscert/ncas/tips/ST08-001).